# How can I get GNU 'find' to find the *first* instance of a filename in a directory tree?

Tags: linux, find, gnu

The '-depth' global switch is documented as forcing a depth-first search, but even without that switch I seem to get a depth-first search, and that's not what I want. In particular, I want it to output a matching file in a directory *before* it recurses into subdirectories.

Note in this example it finds 12/KeyboardTest/Main.jack *before* it finds 12/Keyboard.jack.

```
$ find . -name "*.jack"
./12/KeyboardTest/Main.jack
./12/Keyboard.jack
./12/Math.jack
./12/Screen.jack
./12/String.jack
./12/Output.jack
./12/Memory.jack
./12/MemoryTest/Main.jack
./12/Sys.jack
./12/ArrayTest/Main.jack
./12/SysTest/Main.jack
./12/ScreenTest/Main.jack
./12/OutputTest/Main.jack
./12/StringTest/Main.jack
./12/MathTest/Main.jack
./12/Array.jack
```

(I happen to be doing this under Cygwin; I don't *think* that's relevant, but I mention it in case it is.)

I could certainly write my own bash or perl code to do this, but that seems...excessive?  I must just be overlooking a way to get find to do this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

The -depth option has find evaluate the contents of a directory before the directory itself.  The contents of the directory is *everything* in the directory, whether it be a file or a directory.  It's the difference between:

```
foo
foo/file1
foo/dir
foo/dir/file
foo/file2
```

and:

```
foo/file1
foo/dir/file
foo/dir
foo/file2
foo
```

`foo` came before vs after the items in `foo`, while the order of those items, `file1`, `file2`, and `dir`, is unchanged.

find doesn't sort, so won't be able to just use find to do what you want.  Something following a decorate, sort, un-decorate pattern might work for you.  Consider prefixing each item with its depth via `-printf "%d %p\n"`, then piping the output to sort -n.  From my list above, we'd get:

```
$ find foo -name "file*" -printf "%d %p\n" | sort -n
1 foo/file1
1 foo/file2
2 foo/dir/file
```

That looks like the order you wanted.  Strip the depth number with "cut" or "awk" and you have your list.  Pipe it to xargs if you wanted to run a command on those files rather than just list them.

At three levels deep, you might not find the sort order to be what you had in mind, though it does satisfy your stated requirement.

```
1 foo/file1
2 foo/dir1/file
2 foo/dir2/file
3 foo/dir1/subdir/file
```

Perhaps you really wanted those last two lines to be in the opposite order.  That will be harder!